# Why is there no Java compiler on Android?

Tags: java

I'm not an Android developer but I do other stuff.

I just rooted my phone so I was playing around with a shell and I was trying to compile some C packages and realized there is no C compiler, OK.

Surely there must be Java right? Tried it and I can't get a `java` or `javac` command to work either.

How is that possible when Android apps are written in Java?

Comment: First, because Android devices are intended for end-users (sure also for developers, but they are in a minority ;) Second, your PC didn't ship with a compiler either, right? So third, you might have to install one. There are several IDEs available which run on Android – but this site here isn't for software recommendations :)

Comment: I get that part....but how do the apps run with no Java?

Comment: Running already compiled apps doesn't need a compiler being installed, right? We don't run them from source :) Depending on the Android version, there's some bytecode optimization done by either the Dalvik (< 5.0) or the ART (5.0+) engine, though, but that's something different. To give you a hint: To *run* a Java app on a PC, you need the JRE (Java Runtime Environment) – to *compile* a Java app from its source you need the JDK (Java Development Kit). Two different pairs of shoes, though the latter contains the former :)

Comment: OK I guess I thought the java command i tried to run was part of the jre? No?

Comment: You might wish to check our [chat room](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/25/android-enthusiasts) – comments are not for discussion :) Short answer: for compiling, definitely no. And while Android apps are mostly written in Java, things are a bit different here. Goes to deep for this site, which is for end-users.

Comment: Apps are launched by the **Application Manager**, which is a part of **am.jar**. To start an Android app, you need to use the `am` command, which calls a script, _which_ sets the am.jar as `CLASSPATH` and then executes `exec app_process $base/bin com.android.commands.am.Am "$@"` (`base` being `/system`). Look inside **/system/bin/am** for details.

Comment: Android doesn't run Java bytecode because it uses Dalvik VM. And developers distribute apk packages, not Java/C#/kotlin source code

Answer (score 1):

If you have Android 5.0 (lollipop) or later, use [`termux`](https://termux.com/). (Terminal IDE is great but only works up to android 4.*). It's on the google play store, and the source is on github.

It has an `apt` repository with several compilers, including `ecj`, the
`Eclipse Compiler for Java`, and is *much* faster than `javac`.

There's also `golang`, `clang`, `gcc`, `node`, `python` and a whole bunch of other stuff (`tmux`, `vim`, `ctags`, `cscope`, `emacs`, `latex`etc etc etc).

NB: this doesn't actually answer your "why" question, but might be helpful...

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can install a Java compiler but don't expect to be able to create your own applications for Android on Android.

I asked a [similar question here](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/169003/decompile-recompile-apk-on-android-device).

Answer (score 0):

ECJ (Eclipse Compiler for Java) can be ported very easily on Android. I've done it - but no support for Java 8 though.

Also, it is possible to build Android apps on Android, there are apps that already exist for that, JavaIDEdroid is one.