# Decompile/Recompile Apk on Android device

Tags: apk

So I am running Phoenix OS and I have installed Termux.

Is there a way to decompile and then recompile an apk inside of android.
I see this required for Apps here and there but I don't have a physical computer.

Comment: "I see this required for Apps here and there" - huh? Examples?

Comment: @AndyYan that's a fair question http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/25999/is-there-an-app-for-searching-installed-apps-dumb-search-alternative

Comment: Then keep in mind that APK-related tools on Android are often incomplete in function compared to their PC counterparts. Also, with the current complexity of Google App, I doubt whether it can still be decomp'd properly - last I did a decomp/recomp to it, it failed at recomp.

Comment: @AndyYan hmm that is said I like the web because everything is essentially open source to be viewed and edited.  I was hoping to get a similar experience on android.

Comment: @AndyYan where are you getting such information that apps can't be recompiled?  If I ask another question could you explain the current situation?

Comment: I had a similar occasion about a year ago where I had to decomp/recomp Google App to change some resources, but it failed on me, so I gave it up. I don't know about the current situation, though, so it's still worth your try.

Comment: @AndyYan What was the error?

Comment: @DeathMaskSalesman Can't remember precisely, it's been a while. I only knew it was a complaint thrown out by `apktool`.

Comment: @AndyYan Hmm. Did you run it from Windows?

Comment: @DeathMaskSalesman Sure. It could be anything that caused the failure though - I was using the command line back then and naturally it could introduce human errors.

Comment: @AndyYan It's just a guess, but I think that the error might've been related to the encoding. Once, I tried to recompile a particular APK, which failed due to ApkTool using ISO-8859-1 instead of UTF-8, whilst some resource folder sported a non-ASCII name. Recompiling on Linux succeeded, as did removing the oddly named resource.

Comment: There is the original [APKTool](https://github.com/iBotPeaches/Apktool) by iBotPeaches & friends and there is a version modified by [AndroBlack](https://www.xda-developers.com/decompile-and-modify-apks-on-the-go-with-apktool-for-android/) for use on Android directly. There are x86 compatible versions on [AndroidFileHost](https://www.androidfilehost.com/?w=profile&uid=24562946973631820) linked to from the post there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, here is the official response from the [developer here](http://read%20speeds%20of%20550%20MB/s%20and%20write%20speeds%20of%20520%20MB/s).
To quote

> We leverage a couple of Java7 features that aren't completely in AOSP
>   yet. Most of this being the java.nio2 library. Additionally our YAML
>   library (SnakeYAML isn't compatible on top of Android).
>
> Finally, our native binary (aapt) that has builds for Mac 64/32, Unix
>   64/32 and Windows doesn't have an ARM build for AOSP. That is why.

Comment: What's that link supposed to be? Not working for me -- pops up as `http://read%20speeds%20of%20550%20mb/s%20and%20write%20speeds%20of%20520%20MB/s` and I definitely don't have that copied into my clipboard, lol.

Comment: @l3l_aze trying searching github.  That is where it likely came from.  Either that or the official website.  Sorry been a while since I have messed with this.